# Why is my slideshow not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I've got a slideshow running on jquery, but it looks like there's a bug in it. Cause when you load the page for the first time, you'll see the first wallpaper fade in and fade out a couple of times, after that the slideshow displays correctly..

Can someone help me find out what's wrong?

This is the script I'm using:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function() {
                $('#slideshow > div:first')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('#slideshow');
            }, 3000);
        </script>
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2WYMu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your elements don't exist at the time this script executes so they are not hidden.  Put the code inside [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function(){
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    /* ... */
});
```